# If $L_1,\,L_1L_2$ are regular languages with $L_1\neq \emptyset,\,\lambda\notin L_1,\,\lambda\notin L_2,$ is $L_2$ regular?

Tags: regular-languages

If $L_1,\,L_1L_2$ are regular languages with $L_1\neq \emptyset,\,\lambda\notin L_1,\,\lambda\notin L_2,$ is $L_2$ regular?

I think I found a correct proof for this question but my professor says it cannot work. Her issue is with the right quotient step but I cannot see why it is incorrect. Can anyone shed some light on this?

$$
L_1L_2 = \{ w_1w_2 : w_1 \in L_1,\, w_2 \in L_2 \} \qquad \vert w_1 \vert \ge 1,\, \vert w_2 \vert \ge1
$$

$$
\left( L_1L_2 \right)^R = \{ w_2^Rw_1^R : w_1 \in L_1,\, w_2 \in L_2 \}
$$

$$
\left( L_1L_2 \right)^R / L_1^R = \{ w_2^R : w_2 \in L_2 \} \qquad (w_1^R \in L_1^R)(\forall w_2^Rw_1^R) \implies w_2^R \in \left( L_1L_2 \right)^R / L_1^R
$$

$$
\left( \left( L_1L_2 \right)^R / L_1^R \right)^R = \{ w_2 : w_2 \in L_2 \} = L_2
$$

$$
L_2 \, \text{is regular by closure of reversal and right quotient on regular languages.}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? $L_1=\{a^n\mid n>0\}$, $L_2 = \{a^{m^2}\mid m>0\}$. Certainly $L_1$ and $L_1L_2$ are regular, but $L_2$ certainly isn't.

Comment: Took me a minute to think of how your $L_1L_2$ is regular but I see it now, nice counter example. I have a feeling my right quotient captures $L_2^R$, but also other strings.

Answer (score 1):

Hint #1:

> Try to find a counterexample.

Hint #2:

> What happens in the special case where $L_1 = \Sigma^+$?  Can you solve that special case?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\Sigma=\{a\}$. Let $L_1=\ell_{reg}=\{a^n\mid n>1\},L_2=\ell_{prime}=\{a^m\mid m\text{ is prime number}\}.$

According to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550522/how-to-prove-that-l-ap-p-is-prime-isnt-regular), $\ell_{prime}$ isn't regular. But
$$\ell_{reg}\cdot\ell_{prime}=\ell_{reg}\cdot\{a^2,a^3,a^5,\dots\}.$$
So we can conclude that $$ \ell_{reg}\cdot\ell_{prime}=a^+a^2.$$

But $\ell_{prime}$ isn't regular,as a result, $L_2$ can be  non-regular.